# alert()実施時のsetInterval()動作について

Tags: javascript

setInterval()によるカウント処理中にalert()でメッセージを表示した場合、
メッセージを閉じない限りカウント処理が停止してしまします。
alert()によるメッセージ表示中にもカウントを継続させる方法はありますでしょうか。

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        let val = 0;
        setInterval(count, 1000);
        function count() {
            $("#count").val(val);
            val++;
        }

        $(document).on('click','#alert', function (){
            alert("アラート");
        })
    });
</script>

<div class="container">
    <input id="count"/>
    <button id="alert">アラート</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

alertが開いているときにスクリプトの実行は停止します。 この動作を変更することはできません。
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Window/alert

もしどうしてもモーダルを表示をしている間もスクリプトを実行したいということであれば、ブラウザのモーダル機能ではなく、javascript+HTMLでモーダル表示を使いましょう。

例えば
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

Comment: 補足ですが、Javascriptはシングルスレッドであるため、アラート時に他の処理をすることができません。http://chuckwebtips.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/08/19/070000